# Azure App Service Architecture understanding: Per-App Scaling

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Regarding this MSDN article; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt793270

**Per-App Scaling** section has below paragraphs.

> Using the earlier 50 app example, with per-app scaling enabled for the App Service Plan, all 50 apps can be assigned to the same App Service Plan. Then, the scaling characteristics of individual apps can be modified:
>
> - 40 low-volume applications set to run on a maximum of a single server each.
> - Five mid- to low-volume applications set to run on a maximum of two servers each.
> - Five remaining high-volume applications set to run on a maximum of 10 servers.
>
> The underlying App Service Plan can start out with a minimum of five servers. And then auto-scale rules can be set to scale out as needed based on memory pressure vs. CPU.

I cannot understand why above three configuration gives *minimum of five* servers as a starting count.

Does it say 40 low-volume apps to 1 server, 5 mid-volume apps to 1 servers, and rest 5 high-volume apps to (undescribed) 3 servers?

Comment: I think you're misreading that article. It was merely making up a scenario where you split up your apps into separate App Service Plans. And you also misread the numbers: The example would give minimum 7 instances, not 5 (40 low volume in one app service plan, scaled to just one unit; the 5-mid-volume in another app service plan, scaled to just one unit; the remaining 5 each getting their own app service plan, scaled initially to one unit apiece, resulting in minimum 7 instances). But... that has zero to do with App Service architecture - it's a made up example.

Answer (score 2):

That article is giving examples of splitting up your numerous apps across multiple app services.

The TL;DR version: With an App Service plan, *every app deployed to that app service plan resides on every instance*. If you have an App Service plan with 3 instances, then every one of your apps lives on those 3 instances. Go to 4 instances? Again - all your web apps, api apps, etc. go onto all 4 instances.

If that scale model doesn't work for you (e.g. you have a super-high-load app that eats up all the memory or all the cpu), then maybe that individual app is a candidate for its own app service plan, so that it doesn't starve the other apps in the app service plan.

That's really it. Want to put all your apps in a single app service plan? Great - do it. You have a high-demand app causing issues with your low-volume apps? Great - move it to its own app service plan. Totally up to you.

But that article... is just giving an example of splitting up apps into several app service plans.

Comment: Thanks. I'm translating this article (will official posted to local MSDN site), so I'd like to understand correctly. So, did this article mistype (not my misread) seven to five as minimum count?

Comment: The article doesn't say five. It says seven minimum.

Comment: Actually there are two things in the article . And you're talking about the per-app scaling feature. And again, the five server minimum is just an example. I think we've gone off topic now as we're now going deep into how that article is written and how they are writing examples.

Comment: Ah... last clarification; _"The underlying App Service Plan can start out with a minimum of five servers"_ is not a specification of AppServicePlan, not a minimum requirement of given three bullets separation, but just a user-configured example. Am I right?

Comment: For those new to the terminology, think of App Service Plan as "VM", rather than "pricing plan". An App Service Plan may have multiple instances, may autoscale, etc. There are subtleties you need to figure out with experience too: reporting on mem/CPU usage IS affected by how you split your apps across both resource groups and plans.WebJob background processes may or may not want to be run in parallel, and different types of webjob run on multiple or single instances etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, `a minimum of five servers` statement is calculated as below setup.

- 40 small apps are set to 1 server, fixed value.
- 5 medium apps are set to minimum 1 to maximum 2 server for each.
- 5 large apps are set to minimum 1 to maximum to 10 server for each.

Therefore, *"The underlying App Service Plan can start out with a minimum of five servers"* are given by the number of large apps. Each large app are allocated to each server and rest of them (40small+5mid) might be belonged to one of five.

Please leave a comment if my understanding is not correct.